# Background image of div replaced with screenshot in linux Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, linux, firefox

I have created a game that has fixed size div with a jpg in the background. Everything works ok in all the browsers on windows... but when I try the game on my linux computer at University the div is replaced by a screen shot...

I am baffled... any ideas... will provide more info people think may be useful for solving the problem.

Here is a screen shot of how it looks on my linux computer...
[image]

Here is what it should look like...
[image]

When I change windows or tabs the screen shot div background image changes. For example, If I pop up a terminal, the terminal appears in the background of the div...

[image]

Comment: The screen shot changes every time I switch to another tab and then back to my game. Can you elaborate on how it might be a cache/memory issue...

Comment: The game is available at mouse-master.appspot.com

Comment: My linux computer is running centos, and my firefox is Firefox 10.0. I am behind the University proxy... could that have anything to do with it??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute web links that targets to your image in your css :

```
background:url(http://mouse-master.appspot.com/images/mouseMasterBackground.jpg);
```

I think that it could be a target problem with linux navigator, which displays the index while he can't find a pic, or it is a proxy problem with your university...